# ListView header - different margin

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, margin

I am creating a layout with a listview and some other views. I want complete layout to scroll with list so I am adding the other views as header. The problem is that my listview has some margin which is applied to the header as well.

[image: what it currently looks like]

What should I change so that the header looks something like this-

[image: What I want]

**ListView**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="@color/background_color">

    <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:id="@+id/lvProfileAddresses"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:divider="@color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:cacheColorHint="@color/background_color"
            android:fadingEdgeLength="3dp"

            />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Header**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="@color/transparent"
              >
    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="@color/white"
              android:text="My Addresses"
              android:textSize="20sp"
              android:padding="10dp"
              android:textColor="@color/black"
            />
    <Button android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add New Address"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/small_list_arrow"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/linearlayout_shadow"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

How to make the ListView's header have a different margin?

Comment: How are you adding the header to Listview?

Comment: @MysticMagic Inflating the view and using `listview.addHeaderView()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think It would be better to not to add Header in a ListView, and keep a separate Header. May be you can use `include` for that.

Something like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_color">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        layout="@layout/header" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:id="@+id/lvProfileAddresses"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:divider="@color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:cacheColorHint="@color/background_color"
        android:fadingEdgeLength="3dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

You just need that once in ListView at top. So I think this would be a better approach. Hope it helps.

EDIT:

As you need to keep header inside ListView for scrolling it along with ListView items, you can probably go with other way:

1. Remove the margin properties from entire ListView.
2. Apply the margin to ListView's row_item.xml. For this, you would need to include your row.xml's outer container inside another parent container, say LinearLayout. So margin will work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: but wouldn't this make header non scrollable with list? I want my full layout to scroll with the list.

Comment: Then I guess you can remove margin from whole listview and give margin to list_row.xml @RohanKandwal

Comment: padding is working but it will make the views inside list_row.xml to move inwards, it won't shrink the whole row i.e. the row will still stretch to complete width.

Comment: @RohanKandwal If you put your row layout in side another parent LinearLayout, and apply margin to the row layout, that should work. Did you try that way?

Comment: that's a nice idea, let me try it.

Comment: that worked, thanks. Don't know why it didn't occur to me ;) Can you please post your answer as solution so that I can accept it?

Comment: @MagicalPhoenixϡ Could you edit your answer to provide an example of applying the margin to the row layout?

Comment: @Duncan what's confusion in that?

Comment: @MagicalPhoenixϡ I'm just new to Android and don't really understand how I would do that.

Comment: @Duncan show me your row.xml, I would suggest what you can do.

Comment: @MagicalPhoenixϡ Are you expecting that I have an XML file defining the layout of each list row item? If so, I don't have that currently, so perhaps that's why I didn't entirely understand your answer.

Comment: Not each row item @Duncan .. you should probably first read a tutorial. [See this](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=9) and [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-listview-with-adapter-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with header you need to remove margin attributes from your listview because it affects all children and add the same margin for your listItem.

Comment: adding margin for listItem isn't working. When margin is removed from listview, child expand to full width.

Comment: I'm sorry. It's because ListView.LayoutParams not a child of MarginLayoutParams. So you can put your listitem inside framelayout with transparent background and set padding to that frame layout

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem recently, From what I saw on the platform some people are still struggling with this.
Based on my research It looks like the listview will override the header margins as well as paddings.

The solution will be:

1. to put your header viewgroup inside another viewgroup whose 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" and android:layout_width="match_parent".
2. Then apply whatever margins you want to the inner viewgroup.

In your case the header layout  would look like this :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout 
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_marginTop ="40dp" //For Example
              android:layout_marginRight="20dp" 
              android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
              android:background="@color/transparent">

            <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="@color/white"
              android:text="My Addresses"
              android:textSize="20sp"
              android:padding="10dp"
              android:textColor="@color/black"/>

              <Button android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Add New Address"
              android:drawableRight="@drawable/small_list_arrow"
              android:layout_margin="5dp"
              android:paddingTop="5dp"
              android:paddingBottom="5dp"
              android:background="@drawable/linearlayout_shadow"/>

      </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps